# how to integrate spring with oracle bpm

Tags: java, spring, oracle, business-process-management

Hi can any body please tell me how to integrate spring with oracle bpm.My application is based on spring and here i am using spring-jdbc for data base connection, i am calling a procedure in procedure i have one select query and followed by two update queries, then after fetching records i am calling bpm's updateTaskOutCome method. if bpm returns success there is no problem, in case if bpm fails the problem is in procedure i already updated the tables, but it should not happen like that, the transaction should be role base, since these two applications are running in different weblogic server domains transaction role back is not happening. from my spring application i am calling the bpm using bpm jar . how can i handle this please can any body explain me.